# Pass value and call controller from view in laravel

Tags: laravel, view, controller

I have view. It looks like this :
[image]
When I click on the cell of column id The system get the value and pass to controller and call a function in the controller

I wrote in view

```
<?php
    use App\Http\Controllers\pu_po_estimateController;
?>

@section('scripts')
<script>
function onChange(arg)
{
  var POID = $.map(this.select(), function(item) 
  {return $(item).text();});

  {!! pu_po_estimateController::ShowPODetail(POID); !!}
}
</script>
@endsection
```

The code in controller

```
public static function ShowPODetail($MyPOID)
  {
   print_f($MyPOID);
  }
```

But It does not work. Plese help how to pass value and call controller from view.

Thank you very much indeed !!!

Comment: You need to make a route, link the controller function to that route and then call the route from javascript. You can't just call controller methods in your view.

Comment: use AJAX to call controller function from view.